# C++ regex library; how to tell which alternation(s) was matched

Tags: c++, regex, ecmascript-5

Using the C++ regex library with the default modified ECMAscript grammar, I want to be able to use `regex_search` to test whether strings match a regular expression `rx1|rx2|rx3`, where `rx1`, `rx2` and `rx3` are regular expressions, *and*, if there is a match (i e, if `regex_search` returns true), I want to know which of the `rx`'s was matched. It is possible that a string will match more than one of the `rx`'s; in that case, I want to know all of them.

I know how to capture the matches, and I suppose I could compare the match details, but this is really tricky. I'm looking for something simple--something that says "rx1 was matched", etc.

For a simple example, suppose `rx1` is `A([[:digit::]+)`, `rx2` is `B([[:digit::]+)`, and `rx3` is `C([[:digit::]+)`. Here I have captured the digit string, and I want to know whether the test string is an A, B, or C. My real strings are much more complex, so capturing the initial letter would not suffice, and in any case would depend on the number of captures in each `rx`.

Comment: I think that you have to rematch your capture matches to check which ones match.